# Angular submit form inside form?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I wanna send a form inside a form, but when I submit the form-inside-the-form, all the forms are submitted now.
Is it even possible to do this?

```
<form name="add_foobar_form" novalidate ng-submit="addFoobar(foobar)">

    <form name="send_contact_form" novalidate ng-submit="sendContact(hello)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="hello.bye">
        <input type="submit" value="sendmall">
    </form>

    <input type="text" ng-model="foobar.go">
    <input type="submit" value="sendall">

</form>
```

Comment: It's better do not nest form inside form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms
 you can try form tag for submit button http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

Answer (score 21):

[**Can you have nested forms?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms) Simply no, Nested form won't work.

> **[Docs Says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)**
>
> In Angular, forms can be nested. This means that the outer form is
>   valid when all of the child forms are valid as well. However, browsers
>   do not allow nesting of  elements, so Angular provides the
>   ngForm directive which behaves identically to  but can be
>   nested. This allows you to have nested forms, which is very useful
>   when using Angular validation directives in forms that are dynamically
>   generated using the ngRepeat directive

But unfortunately you could not use the `ng-submit` form, that will call the parent `ng-submit` method on click of any inner form.

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VG7QNnsM8u0eggWPT184?p=preview)

Workaround for this would be don't use `ng-submit` directive for the inner nested from. You should use `ng-click` on button and change type of button to `button` from `submit`.

**Markup**

```
<form name="add_foobar_form" novalidate ng-submit="addFoobar('foobar')">
    <ng-form name="send_contact_form" novalidate>
      <input type="text" ng-model="hello.bye">
      <input type="button" value="sendmall" ng-click="sendContact('hello')">
    </ng-form>

    <input type="text" ng-model="foobar.go">
    <input type="submit" value="sendall">
</form>
```

[**Workaround Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZAXaJDgm6uTyAZ18YVy?p=preview)

Comment: the problem is that both cases the same event handler is called